# Connecting an <a> element to draw an image in a HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, html5-canvas

I am trying to use a dropdown button list to display different images in a HTML canvas. I have the href set to utilize javascript and the img and script down by the canvas, yet when you click on the button nothing happens. Am I missing something in the coding, or is there a better way to go about this? I appreciate the input!

```
`<div class="dropdown">
              <button onclick="adultlist()" class="dropbtn">Adults</button>
              <div id="adults" class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa1();">Adult 1</a> 
                  <a href = "#canvas">Adult 2</a> 
                  <a href = "#canvas">Adult 3</a> 
                  <a href = "#canvas">Adult 4</a> 
                  <a href = "#canvas">Adult 5</a> 
                  <a href = "#canvas">Adult 6</a>
                  <a href = "#canas">Adult 7</a> 
                  <a href = "#canvas">Adult 8</a> 
                  <a href = "#canvas">Adult 9</a> 
                  <a href = "#canvas">Adult 10</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
        function adultlist() {
         document.getElementById("adults").classList.toggle("show");
         }
         window.onclick = function(event) {
         if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
         var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
         var i;
         for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
         var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
         if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
         openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
               }
             }
           }
         }
              </script>

 <img id="adult1" width="100" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult1.png"       alt="Adult 1" class="hidden">
    <canvas class="preview" id="canvas" width="250" height="300"> 
      Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.
    </canvas>
<script>
    function drawa1() {
          var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
          var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");
          const img= document.getElementById("adult1").innerHTML = img;
          ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
      };
      </script>``
```

Comment: `const img= document.getElementById("adult1").innerHTML = img` looks suspect. Try just `const img= document.getElementById("adult1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code are in these lines:

```
const img = document.getElementById("adult1").innerHTML = img;
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
```

Firstly, you're assigning a variable to the innerHTML of an element then to itself, which makes no sense. You need to set `img` to the reference of the `img` element so that it can be provided to the `drawImage()` method.

There's also a few other improvements you could make, such as removing the event handlers from the HTML, and relating the `a` elements to the images by their index within the container, instead of having to explicitly assign classes or ids to everything.

Here's a working example with those changes made:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('.dropbtn'))
    return;

  var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-content");
  dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => dropdown.classList.toggle('show'));
});

const dropBtn = document.querySelector('.dropbtn');
const adultsContainer = document.querySelector('#adults');
const adults = adultsContainer.querySelectorAll('a');
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.images-container img');
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const getIndexWithinParent = el => [...el.parentElement.children].indexOf(el);

dropBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  adultsContainer.classList.toggle("show");
});

adults.forEach(adult => {
  adult.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear existing images
    
    const img = images[getIndexWithinParent(e.target)];
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  });
});
```

```css
#adults,
.images-container {
  display: none;
}

#adults.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Adults</button>
  <div id="adults" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Adult 1</a>
    <a href="#">Adult 2</a>
    <a href="#">Adult 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="images-container">
  <img width="100" height="290" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x290/ccc/fff.png&text=Adult+1" alt="Adult 1" />
  <img width="100" height="290" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x290/ccc/fff.png&text=Adult+2" alt="Adult 1" />
  <img width="100" height="290" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x290/ccc/fff.png&text=Adult+3" alt="Adult 1" />
</div>

<canvas class="preview" id="canvas" width="250" height="300"> 
  Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.
</canvas>
```